# Filtering Out Specific Value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter out a specific value in a column, but the record feature seems to only support selecting specific values to keep instead of take out.

For example, if the column is filled with arbitrary words not known beforehand, I want to make sure a specific word is not there. If a column was filled with names of fruits, I would want to take out "apple" without having to know the name of every other fruit in there.

I would have to select every fruit but "apple" to filter "apple" out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$21").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>apple", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

just as an example.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for. Guess it was just a matter of getting the right conditional, thanks.