# How to assign the filter button to data in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I searched on SO about this topic and I generally found how to filter data ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411375/excel-vba-macro-for-filtering-out-specific-value), for example), but this is not my goal.

I wrote a script that successfully adds some new columns (containing data) next to the existing ones. The filter button is already active on the preexisting columns (see later).

What I want to do is simply "activating" the `Filter button` also on the new columns (`"res1`" and `"res2"`) using VBA. This is my starting situation:

[image]

and this what I want to achieve:

[image]

Starting from the selection of the output sheet:

```
Sheets(out_sheet).Select '# out_sheet is a string
```

what can I do? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add columns to the AutoFilter, you can simply remove and recreate the AutoFilter.

[image: Autofilter]

By recording a macro while doing that, and then viewing the VBA that was generated, I found that running this line:

```
Range("A:E").AutoFilter
```

...will create an AutoFilter for columns A:E.

Running it *again* removes the filter.

Comment: I tried, but I probably miss something. Do I have to add your line after the selection of the sheet (i.e. the line I wrote as an example)? There is an additional problem: since I don't know how many rows I have as input, I can't use a predefined letter as the end of the range (e.g. "E"), but I should automatically retrieve the last non-blank column.

Comment: The number of rows don't matter.  If you want to apply the AutoFilter to columns `A` to `G` on `Sheets(out_sheet)` then the only line you need is: `Sheets(out_sheet).Range("A:G").AutoFilter`

Comment: `Sheets(out_sheet).UsedRange.AutoFilter` will apply AutoFilter to all columns that have data.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I didn't notice I applied your suggestion outside the macro, so it wasn't initiated.